# Density of g(X) where g is a differentiable injective function.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, random-variables

Let $X$ have a density $f(x), Y = g (X)$, where $g$ is a differentiable injective function. Find the density of $Y$.

It is clear how to act if G is monotonous, but this is not the case here, and how to work with $ F_Y = P (g(X) \leq x) $

Comment: A continuous real-valued-function is injective if and only if it is strictly monotonous.

Answer (score 0):

If your random variables are real valued then  use the fact that any injective continuous fucntion on $\mathbb R$ is automatically strictly monotonic.